# How to remove row from data frame based on particular format of cell with R

Tags: r, csv, twitter

So I am trying to perform some basic analysis on a .csv from Twitter Analytics. For those of you who don't know, a Twitter Analytics export includes information on all posts and @replies for your account.  However, I only want to look at information for our actual posts.  There is no column specifying whether or not a post is an original or a reply.  The only signal that a post is a reply is that in the "Tweet text" column it always starts with "@" the username.  How can I use R to remove all rows from the .csv that start with @ in the "Tweet text" column?

Comment: Sorry for my lack of clarity, but I am brand new to programming, so it's hard for me to explain what I need...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep()` to do this.

```
# sample data frame
df <- data.frame(text = c("Here's a tweet", 
                          "@user this is a reply", 
                          "another tweet", 
                          "@another reply"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# remove rows beginning with @
df[grep("^@", df$text, invert = TRUE), ]
# [1] "Here's a tweet" "another tweet"
```